# Save and load Universal Sentence Encoder model on different machines

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

How can we save and load an Universal Sentence Encoder model on different machines?

I created a Keras model with USE and saved it on machine A.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

module_url = "/path/on/machine/A/universal-sentence-encoder_4"
emb = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

input1 = Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
embedding_layer = emb(input1)
dense1 = Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(embedding_layer)
outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense1)

model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["AUC"])
model.save("model.h5", include_optimizer=False)
```

Now I want to open `model.h5` on machine B. Pre-trained USE is saved here `/different/path/on/machine/B/universal-sentence-encoder_4`. This is the error I get.

```
model = load_model("model.h5", custom_objects={"KerasLayer": hub.KerasLayer})

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/resolver.py in __call__(self, handle)
    494   def __call__(self, handle):
    495     if not tf.compat.v1.gfile.Exists(handle):
--> 496       raise IOError("%s does not exist." % handle)
    497     return handle
    498 

OSError: /path/on/machine/A/universal-sentence-encoder_4 does not exist.
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a way to save everything including `universal-sentence-encoder_4` into one `model.h5` file so that users do not need to worry about USE?

tensorflow version: `2.4.1` keras version: `2.4.0`

UPDATE: per [WGierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15460480/wgierke)'s advice, created [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17ullsaA0z7vn8SeYlJ78vDIhfmuLZqoF?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you're actually running `load_model("/different/path/on/B/.../model.h5", ...)`? It seems weird that your error message outputs `/path/on/machine/A/... does not exist` even though it's executed on machine B.

Comment: Yeah I know it's wired and I cannot figure out. The path for `model.h5` is correct. When I run `load_model("model.h5")` on machine A it works. But if I rename to say `universal-sentence-encoder_4_renamed` on the same machine, `load_model("model.h5")` stops working with `OSError universal-sentence-encoder_4 does not exist`

Comment: That's indeed weird. Can you provide a complete self-contained script to reproduce it on one machine? You could just fetch a model from tfhub.dev, store it e.g. at /tmp/A, move /tmp/A to /tmp/B and try loading it from /tmp/B. I think this would simplify debugging for us a lot.

Comment: If I change to hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"), load_model("model.h5") works both on machine A and B. This issue happens only when the local USE path is changed. Trying to find a local solution because, my code is behind a corporate firewall and cannot load it from internet. Would you please elaborate a bit more on "provide a complete self-contained script"? I was able to replicate the issue with the code snippet above on my work as well as personal computers.

Comment: `model.to_json()` shows `"handle": "/path/on/machine/A/universal-sentence-encoder_4"`. So the USW path is hardcoded in the model.

Comment: Can you write a script such that it works on https://colab.research.google.com/? Being able to reproduce the issue there would be really helpful for debugging. With the script above, it's unclear e.g. how you saved the model at "/path/on/machine/A/" etc.

Comment: That is a great idea. Created https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17ullsaA0z7vn8SeYlJ78vDIhfmuLZqoF?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is related to what you've observed [in this SO question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70010467): saving a Keras model requires serializing everything that is contained in the model. When you initialize a `hub.KerasLayer` using a generic Callable like `loaded_obj`, it cannot be serialized. Instead, you have to pass a string `handle` that points to the path of the SavedModel (or the tfhub.dev URL). When the Keras model is saved, [`KerasLayer.get_config`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py#L334) is invoked, which stores that string in the config entry with the key `handle`.

When restoring the Keras model, the config is de-serialized and Keras runs `hub.KerasLayer(config["handle"])`. As you can see, this will fail if the model stored at `handle` is not available anymore.

Unfortunately, the only workaround right now is to make sure that the referenced path is also available on machine B.